# Selenium-Webdriver unable to find element in webpage after a page load using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am trying to automate an web application using Selenium Webdriver and C#. Currently I am stuck with a simple issue. After navigating to a particular page, I am trying to click a link which has a link text of "Manage groups". However when I am executing the test it is failing to find the element in the web page.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage groups"));
```

I also tried using absolute Xpath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/article/li[2]/a"));
```

In both the cases the test navigates to the page then fails with error:

> unable to find the element

Comment: Could you add the html or the url of the website? That would make it easier to see what other ways to select the element are.

Comment: It sounds like a timing issue. To confirm this you could add a sleep of 5-10 seconds right before the failing step. If it succeeds with a sleep then you need to figure out what to wait for using `WebDriverWait`, which is an **explicit wait**. Don't keep the sleep. Relevant `html` would help for better answers. side note: absolute **XPath's** are your enemy. **XPath** selectors should include as little information as possible to uniquely identify the element. :)

Comment: Can you see your element after page loaded (without scrolling)? I remember there was an issue with selenium - it can't find elements that not in view

Comment: I have added around 30 secs of wait time but the test fails after waiting. Also the element is visible after the page loads. manually there is no need to scroll in the page to make the element visible.

Comment: Also I am unable to share the url of the website as it is not allowed from my side to share the application link at this point of time.

Comment: Can you share the at least the html around the element you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: @AleksAndreev fwiw, selenium actually can find elements that are not in view. However, if the website has it behind some other element like a header, it might not know that it needs to scroll to get it away from that element before attempting to interact with it.

Comment: @MadTester Without seeing the `html` for the element I can offer a super generalized **XPath**. `//*[contains(text(), 'Manage groups')]`. Or `//a[contains(text(), 'Manage groups')]` if it is indeed an `a` tag. Beware though, this could match several elements. Showing some **html** would get you a better selector for this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be caused by a small mistake in 'Manage groups' text (e.g. there may be an addition whitespace).

1. Can you please provide at least little part of html (you can get it by right-click on your 'Manage groups' link and selecting 'Inspect Element' option )
2. if not - try these ones:

`By.XPath("//a[@contains(., 'Manage groups')]")`

`By.XPath("//a[@contains(., 'manage groups')]")`

`By.XPath("//a[@value='Manage groups')]")`

`By.partialLinkText("Manage groups")`

Answer (score 0):

It should work with that :)

```
IWebElement ClickNext = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Manage groups']"));
// We get the link to click on
ClickNext.Click();
```

Edit : Try that `li` instead of `a`

```
IWebElement ClickNext = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[.='Manage groups']"));
// We get the link to click on
ClickNext.Click();
```

Comment: THis also doesn't work. Gives the same issue as No such element found.

Comment: Ok, Could you give us the Html of the website ?? See my edit in the mean time. We will make it work ;)